# Button doesn't respond on anything when pressed

Tags: android, android-button

What I'm facing is that whenever I press the button to save data to check if the fields is filled up and if it is then it will pass data to back4app but nothing happens even. The Android monitor/Run doesnt even show that the button is being pressed nor the Logcat.

I have a log in activity, register activity, and the main activity. After  Logging in it will take you to the main activity which is empty for now but you need to use the navigation bar to take you to this activity and even the fields are filled or not the button does not respond at all. I put a toast to make sure that the button works but the toast doesnt show.

The code below I just copied in the registration form which is the same concept, fill the form test if theres something in there, if not then message will appear then it will send data to back4app. But the button in this problem doesnt work.

This is the button command

```
package com.example.back4app.userregistrationexample.Classes;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.example.back4app.userregistrationexample.R;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class Purchases extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText establishmentView;
private EditText particularsView;
private EditText amountView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app_bar_purchases);
    establishmentView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edt_Establishment);
    particularsView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edt_Particular);
    amountView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edt_purchasesnumber);

    final Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_purchasessave);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean validationError = false;

            StringBuilder validationErrorMessage = new StringBuilder("Please, insert ");
            if (isEmpty(establishmentView)) {
                validationError = true;
                validationErrorMessage.append("an Establisment");
            }
            if (isEmpty(particularsView)) {
                if (validationError) {
                    validationErrorMessage.append(" and ");
                }
                validationError = true;
                validationErrorMessage.append("a Particular");
            }
            if (isEmpty(amountView)) {
                if (validationError) {
                    validationErrorMessage.append(" and ");
                }
                validationError = true;
                validationErrorMessage.append("a Amount");
            }
            validationErrorMessage.append(".");

            if (validationError) {
                Toast.makeText(Purchases.this, validationErrorMessage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            final ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog(Purchases.this);
            dlg.setTitle("Please, wait a moment.");
            dlg.setMessage("Signing up...");
            dlg.show();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
    });
}

private boolean isEmpty(EditText text) {
    if (text.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean isMatching(EditText text1, EditText text2){
    if(text1.getText().toString().equals(text2.getText().toString())){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

private void alertDisplayer(String title,String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Purchases.this)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Purchases.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    ParseUser.logOut();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog ok = builder.create();
    ok.show();
}
}
```

Edit: This is the app_bar_purchases.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_puchasesbal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Balance" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Edt_Establishment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Establishment"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Edt_Particular"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Particulars"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Edt_purchasesnumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Amount"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_purchasessave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="178dp"
    android:text="Save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Heres what happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O13g.jpg) when I try to debug it and put break in boolean same thing happens when I put the break in button save it doesnt show anything on the Debug no errors or anything

**EDIT** I have pasted the right xml file

**EDIT** Does having RelativeLayout makes the button not respond?

**EDIT** I have pasted the whole java class

**EDIT** I also tried deleting everything else on the onClick except for 
`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` just to see if the button itself works but it didn't even show the toast

Comment: @Railbyfe ,Are you sure the button id is the correct one?

Comment: Yes im pretty sure that is the right button

Comment: brother put break pint to the line " boolean validationError = false;" and dubug the app, you can find the error

Comment: tried doing it but same thing happen and still no response from the button, i add a image in the edit

Comment: @Raibyfe, if your code is fine then try to clean and rebuild project, might be issue with Android Studio indexing.

Comment: I have done it a couple times now and still the button wouldn't respond but when I pressed it on the screen it can be seen being pressed but no response coming from android studio debug/run

Comment: where is xml in which you have `btn_purchasessave`

Comment: @Raibyfe: can you post your complete java code of class fie.

Comment: I have edited it now

Answer (score 0):

I took reference of a SO question,
Try using this :

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

And import this

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

**EDIT**

Casting most of the android views is reduntant now but it can be the problem, Try to caste the button like this :

```
final Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_purchasessave);
```

and try your code.

**EDIT 2**

Try using **save.setOnClickListener(this)** like this,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText establishmentView;
private EditText particularsView;
private EditText amountView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    establishmentView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edt_Establishment);
    particularsView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edt_Particular);
    amountView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edt_purchasesnumber);

    final Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_purchasessave);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

      //do things here

}
```

Comment: Yes that's already in my button command I also tried removing the "final" and still nothing works

Comment: intead of `new view.Onclicklistener` you tried `new OnClickListener()` ? and didn't work?

Comment: Also please post your XML code where this button is created

Comment: I tried using new OnClickListener() but it says Cannot resolve symbol 'OnClickListener'

Comment: It can be only DialogInterface.OnClickListener or View.OnClickListener

Comment: So.. I tried using final Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_purchasessave);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() this code and import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 and i still got no response coming from the button

Comment: I tried your code your xml and java with only Toast in on click , it worked fine shows the Toastmessage

Comment: I tried your whole code except alertDisplayer method and it worked very much fine , toast came with data saved also progress dialog appears, didn't found any problem

Comment: How? I also tried using only toast just to make sure that the button is working...

Comment: Is it possible that the template I used was not able to properly process the function?

Comment: What template you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your button id in xml file it's btn_addbalance

then check your id in java file it's btn_purchasessave

please correct this check below code

your line

```
final Button save = findViewById(R.id.btn_purchasessave);
```

replace with

```
final Button save = findViewById(R.id.btn_addbalance);
```

it will help to you

Comment: Oops my fault I copied the wrong layout file But I edited it now